# Access parent property in child class object

Tags: php, oop

I'm just starting with OO php so please forgive my ignorance.

Assuming I have a class A

```
class A{
    function show(){
        return 15;
        }
    }
```

And a child class B

```
class B extends A{
    function show(){
        return 25;
        }
    }
```

When I do

```
$object = new B;
$object->show();
```

I get 25, meaning I access the child property. How can I access the parent property;

I tried $object->A::show(), $object::show(), I keep getting errors, and since I'm just starting, I don't really know what to google for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thing you want do conflicts basics of object design - if you overwrite parent method, it cannot be called from outside of child instance (inside there is parent:: ). Take a look at your design and try to figure out, how to avoid this.

EDIT:
Both of your examples of calling this are invalid - only valid is

```
class B extends A{
  function show(){
    return parent::show();
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not a real world situation, I am just learnig so I am trying to find my way around the various situations. You are suggesting that what I want is impossible?

Comment: in PHP yes, in C++ for example it can be sloved, but still it is contraproductive, because object B must have complete functionality, so you don't need to call parent methods directly

Answer (score 1):

you are overriding the function show in the child class, so to access it in the parent class you will have to instantiate an object of class a

```
$object = new A();
$object->show();
```

There's now way to acccess the parent objects function show() from and instance of the child class

Comment: I want to do it in a B object. I don't HAVE to since I'm just learning, but I'd like to know how this can be done with a B object.

Comment: you can use parent::show() from inside the child classes show funciton. since this is returning 2 different values there's not really a point doing this though